# sed insert characters between two pattern matches

Tags: insert, sed

I'm working on this text file that has hundreds of lines that look like the condensed version below:

```
# <block_uid>   # <freq> <memop> <fpop> <insn> <line> <fname> <perc>
3941319690354688    # 776547959  2.232946   0
3941427129090048    # 465293088 40  37  74 4.215079 0 
3941427110739968    # 465558912 36  35  68
```

I'm trying to use sed to insert **dfpattern** in between `3941319690354688` and `# 776547959` on each line because the file is way to large to be done manually.
so after a 16 digit pattern and before the `#`
i.e. it will look like this:

```
# <block_uid>   # <freq> <memop> <fpop> <insn> <line> <fname> <perc>
3941319690354688 dfpattern  # 776547959  2.232946   0
3941427129090048 dfpattern  # 465293088 40  37  74 4.215079 0
3941427110739968 dfpattern  # 465558912 36  35  68
```

I'm a novice at sed and I couldn't come up with the command fiddling around so I'm asking for help.
Can you please explain the command you post briefly so I can learn from it.
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try following command. It matches from the beginning of the line (`^`), any number of digits followed by a space with that same content (`\1`) with literal `dfpattern` appended.

```
sed -e 's/^\([0-9]*[ ]\)/\1dfpattern /' infile
```

Output:

```
# <block_uid>   # <freq> <memop> <fpop> <insn> <line> <fname> <perc>
3941319690354688 dfpattern    # 776547959  2.232946   0
3941427129090048 dfpattern    # 465293088 40  37  74 4.215079 0 
3941427110739968 dfpattern    # 465558912 36  35  68
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to replace the first space with <space> `dfpattern` <space>? `s/ / dfpattern /`

Comment: @tripleee: Yes. It also would work, but taking into account to skip header, like `sed -e '2,$ s/ / dfpattern/' infile`

Comment: for some reason it's not working for me: it gives me the same output I started with. but sed -e 's/\([0-9]*[ ]\)/\1dfpattern /g' testing.txt  --changes the output but in the wrong place because I'm not specifying the ^ front of line character.

Comment: @JaneChandler: Why didn't you escape parentheses? It's mandatory in `sed` to group the matched text.

Comment: because copy paste didn't work in the add comment box but I copied pasted your command into the terminal which kept the escape characters

Comment: @JaneChandler: Why did you add the `g` flag at the end of the substitution command? Avoid it for this case. I can't help much more because with your example provided works for me. Also you can try the suggestion of *tripleee*.

Comment: I got it to work if I used your exact command but took out [ ]  I don't know why this froze it up before but now it works. Thank you!

Comment: @JaneChandler: It wasn't neccesary, it was to emphasize that there was an space there. Glad you got it :-)